# How can I programatically display the window's system (titlebar) menu

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, menu, skin

My dialog doesn't have any non-client area, because I want to paint a custom titlebar. But that means the system menu isn't shown when the user clicks on the titlebar.

I've changed WM_NCHITTEST to respond with HTCLIENT for my titlebar, and I can capture the WM_NCRBUTTONUP message, but I need help about showing the system menu, I can't find out how to do this properly.

So far I have this:

```
void CSkinnedDialog::OnNcRButtonUp( UINT nHitTest, CPoint point )
{
    CMenu* pMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (int cmd = pMenu->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_RETURNCMD, point.x, point.y, this))
        SendMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND, cmd, MAKELPARAM(point.x, point.y));
}

void CSkinnedDialog::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

LRESULT CSkinnedDialog::OnNcHitTest( CPoint point )
{
    LRESULT res = CDialog::OnNcHitTest(point);
    ScreenToClient(&point);
    if (res == HTCLIENT && point.y < m_nFrameHeight)
    {
        res = HTCAPTION;
    }
    return res;
}

void CSkinnedDialog::SysMenuAddAboutEntry()
{
    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.
    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
    pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
    pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, "About...");
    }
}
```

It shows the system menu, but it doesn't work very well. It doesn't respond to all the commands the user can select (for example, clicking on the "About..." menu entry doesn't do anything, and some of the actions that should be disabled and grayed out, like maximize and restore, aren't until you've clicked at least once with the left button on the titlebar.

Comment: You want to have a caption bar and a system menu. I suggest you include window styles that make the system draw it. Why would you need to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: My dialog is skinned. Everything, including the titlebar, has to be painted with bitmaps, so I can't let the system draw the titlebar.

Comment: You should set the WS_SYSMENU style, then write your own owner drawn menu class. use GetSystemMenu to subclass the system menu and then you'll have a skinned system menu! Obviously you can use TrackPopupMenu to display it where ever you want.

Comment: I'd take a look at this project: http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~kent/Cs233/code/Prosise/chap07/Clock/Clock.cpp it works well, I have used its methods in my own projects aswell.